# Complex number to polar form with exponent Help?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$z^{11} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} -\frac{i}{2}$$

I should write this to polar form (se picture). I got my answer to $z^{11}$, but not $z$:
$$z^{11} = \cos(-5\pi/6) + i\sin(-5\pi/6).$$

How do I get it to $z$? My original thought is that $-5\pi/6$ turns into $-5\pi/66$, basically $6\cdot 11$ in denominator.

Is this correct? I have a bunch of these problems, so would really help. Thanks!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Add $10\pi$ to your angle. Result easily divisible by 11.

Comment: You have a good idea but it needs to be formalized: $z=e^{it}$ with $11t\equiv-5\pi/6+k2\pi$ ($k\in\Bbb Z$),  i.e. $t\equiv-5\pi/66+k2\pi/11,$ which gives eleven solutions $t\bmod{2\pi},$ i.e. eleven solutions $z.$

Comment: Remember, in the complex numbers, a polynomial equation $P(z) = 0$ where $P$ is an $n$-degree polynomial always has $n$ solutions (counting multiplicity, but in this case the polynomial $z^{11} - \alpha = 0$ does not have multiples of any root, where $\alpha$ is the given value).